# Pdf.js (for node) not rendering entire contents of pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to search the text of of a pdf using https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist-for-node.

My code looks like this:

```
 gettext: function(){
     var data = '../static/example.pdf';
         return pdfjs.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
     var pages = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < pdf.numPages; i++) {
                 pages.push(i);
     }
     return Promise.all(pages.map(function(pageNumber) {
                 return pdf.getPage(pageNumber + 1).then(function(page) {
         return page.getTextContent().then(function(textContent) {
                         return textContent.items.map(function(item) {
             return item.str;
                         }).join(' ');
         });
                 });
     })).then(function(pages) {
         return pages.join("\r\n")
     });
         }).then(function(pages){
     console.log(pages)
     });


 }
```

This seems to work, but it skips parts of the text.  Specifically, it skips whatever I can't highlight with the mouse in the original pdf doc.  Is there a way to get pdf.js to pick up on this data?

Comment: See https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist for official repo and example at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.js

Comment: The sources for pdfjs-dist-for-node cannot be found to tell how old that PDF.js fork is or if it's a malicious one. I would recommend stop using it and start using the official fork.

Comment: @async5  Thanks for the heads up, I switched over to pdfjs-dist.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is not selectable when you view the PDF, that means it's actually an *image*, which therefore means you won't be able to search for it.

So unfortunately, this is not possible, unless you set up something else to do some OCR on the PDF first to try to convert images to text.

Comment: The text I want to get comes from fields that are editable inside of Acrobat Reader.  When I click one of the fields, it turns into an input that can be edited (including copied + pasted).  I don't think this would be possible if these fields were images.  Nevertheless, when I simply press Select All, these aren't highlighted.