# How to finalize edits in a PDF so that text is selectable?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

I'm working on a pdf doc that includes input fields that have been edited.  I'd like to be able to press *select all* and get all text from the document, but for some reason none of the input fields are included.  Others have told me that if text isn't selectable, it must be an image, but in this case it's not - so is there a way to 'finalize' the edits and select the text?  Maybe turn the doc into read only?

Edit:  I've tried changing it to a read-only doc and it doesn't make the inputs selectable.

Comment: what do you mean by ***finalize***? Also, it would be good if you could show us your code so that we can help you correct/improve it.

Comment: @GeomanYabes  I'm using pdf.js to try to get the text content from a pdf, but some content is missing because it's an editable field (I don't know why this makes a difference, but as I said, it isn't selectable).  I don't know what I mean by finalize, which is why I put it in quotes -- I'd like to know if there's some way to make the contents of input fields selectable.

Comment: @GeomanYabes  Here's code from my pdf.js solution, but it isn't necessarily related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868315/pdf-js-for-node-not-rendering-entire-contents-of-pdf?noredirect=1#comment74775380_43868315

Comment: you should edit your question, include the reference to your code as you mentioned. change tags to `pdfjs` and add `javascript` tag.

Comment: @GeomanYabes  This question doesn't involve javascript or my other question; it could be asked by someone who isn't even touching code.  It's just a pdf question --- *how does one make fields in a pdf that have editable inputs inclusive in select all?*

Comment: by ***select all*** you mean `ctrl+A`, not programatically?

Comment: @GeomanYabes  Correct

Comment: Ctrl+A selects only all the text in the page content, but text fields (just like other annotations) are not part of the content. If you want the field contents to be selectable,  flatten the form into the content.

Comment: @mkl  Do you know if there is a way of flattening the form into the content programmatically -- preferably with pdf.js?

Comment: There are ways to flatten PDFs programmatically. But I only know solutions of that for Java and .Net libraries (as that's my usual programming context).

Comment: @mkl   Got it, thanks